# java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://nnn.nn.nn.88:9999. The connection timed out

Tags: jboss7.x, java-7, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to run in `jboss` instance in domain mode. While I do that I am getting the following issue......

> [Host Controller] 12:45:56,535 WARN  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS010900: Could not connect to remote domain controller at remote://nnn.nn.nn.88:9999 -- java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://nnn.nn.nn.88:9999. The connection timed out

I had ran two JBoss instance in domain mode after configuring...

First JBoss instance->

```
./domain.sh -b nnn.nn.nn.88 -Djboss.bind.address.management=nnn.nn.nn.88
```

Second JBoss Instance ->

```
./domain.sh -b nnn.nn.nn.89 -Djboss.domain.master.address=nnn.nn.nn.88 --host-config=host-slave.xml
```

nnn.nn.nn.88 host.xml configuration is as follows...

```
<domain-controller>
       <local/>
</domain-controller>
```

nnn.nn.nn.89 host-slave.xml configuration is as follows...

```
<domain-controller>
      <remote host="${jboss.domain.master.address}" port="${jboss.domain.master.port:9999}" security-realm="ManagementRealm"/>
<domain-controller>
```

I am able to telnet to port 9999 on host nnn.nn.nn.88 from 89..... as I configured by removing loopback ip for public & management port...... Although is it the implication that `<domain-controller>` has `<local/>`....

Please help me to solve this issue... JDK version is JDK 7 Update 80.... EAP 6.3....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HC host.xml and if we use `--host-config=host-slave.xml` that particular xml has to connected with DC under `<domain-controller>` node....

`jboss.domain.master.address` should be Domain Controller address `nnn.nn.nn.88`....

```
<domain-controller>
      <remote host="${jboss.domain.master.address:nnn.nn.nn.88}" port="${jboss.domain.master.port:9999}" security-realm="ManagementRealm"/>
<domain-controller>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the solution article from redhat....

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/218053#

I ran following command for the same configuration which I had while posting this question..... And I got succeeded.....

DC->
`./domain.sh -b my-host-ip1 -bmanagement my-host-ip1`

HC->
`./domain.sh -Djboss.domain.master.address=my-host-ip1 -b my-host-ip2 -bmanagement my-host-ip2`

Although is this way of configuring gives clustering capability to DC and HCs..... I had raised same question to Redhat on the same solution article..... The answer must be yes I hope....

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/218053#comment-975683